Avoid Authentication for Every Test in Playwright
Framework: Nodejs, typescript, Angular
This is the setup of my test:
Using fixture estimatePage in test.beforeAll. The estimatePage fixture used homePage fixture, where the authentication stage happened.
fixtures.ts
export const test = base.extend<fixtures>({
  // Default estimate if estimate isn't provided in the test.
  testEstimateName: '',
  homePage: async ({ page }, use) => {
    // Use exact url as UI mode tends to fail with base url.
    await page.goto(`${process.env.TARGET}${process.env.LANGUAGE}`);

    const loginPage: LoginPage = new LoginPage(page);
    await page.waitForURL(/login.microsoftonline.com/, { waitUntil: Consts.DOM_CONTENT_LOAD });

    // Log into app
    await loginPage.login();

    // Home page
    await page.waitForURL(process.env.LANGUAGE, { waitUntil: Consts.DOM_CONTENT_LOAD });
    const homePage: HomePage = new HomePage(page);

    // Use the fixture value in the test.
    await use(homePage);

    // Clean up the fixture.
    await homePage.page.close();
  },
  estimatePage: async ({ homePage, testEstimateName }, use) => {
    const estName: string = testEstimateName;
    const currentPage: Page = await homePage.openEstimate(estName);
    const estimatePage = new EstimatePage(currentPage);

    // Use the fixture value in the test.
    await use(estimatePage);

    // Clean up the fixture.
  },
});

The tests are inside a for-loop which are grouped together by test.describe. I also used the test.beforeAll hoping that it will only authenticate once, return the authenticated page so I can use it for all the tests inside the loop. However, everytime a new test in the loop run, the test.beforeAll run again. I run the test on VSCode as debug mode (UI).
test.spec.ts
let estimatePageVal: EstimatePage;
let commonFunctions: CommonFunctions;

// Override the default estimate in the fixture
const estimateName: string = '';
test.use({ testEstimateName: `${estimateName}` });

test.beforeAll(async ({ estimatePage }) => {
  estimatePageVal = estimatePage as EstimatePage;
  commonFunctions = new CommonFunctions(estimatePageVal.page) as CommonFunctions;
});

test.describe('Estimate Line Extension', () => {
  for (let i: number = 0; i < Inputs.length; i++) {
    const input: InputData = Inputs[i];
    const output: OutputData = Outputs[i];
    let detailRowData: UnionModel;
    test(`Test #${i + 1}`, async () => {
      // Switch sheetname to detail
      await estimatePageVal.switchSheet(Consts.DETAIL);
      const sheetName: string = await estimatePageVal.getSheetName();
      await expect(sheetName).toEqual(Consts.DETAIL);

      const bidItem: string = (await estimatePageVal.getCellValue(65, BindColsCEUP.BID_ITEM, sheetName)) as string;
      await expect(bidItem).toEqual('NEW');
    });
  }
});

Edit: I've found the answer but leaving this post here for future reference
https://playwright.dev/docs/test-retries#reuse-single-page-between-tests
